How do I remove a part of a word in a quote? How do I format it?
When you want to add/change a part of a word in a quote you add brackets.
For example: "I am" -> He said that "[he] is"
The quote I am using is: "He was accused of insulting the Ottomans and the Turks by saying that they were not capable of constructing a civilization alone."
My phrase is: As such, the Seljuks did not “construct[] a civilization alone” . . .
I am removing the "-ing" to make it fit with my new phrase however I have a feeling that empty brackets is not how youd show it.

There is a list of permissible changes given in the CMOS (13.7). Changing part of a word to fit it into the surrounding text is not among the permissible changes, except changing the initial letter to capital or lowercase. Otherwise, it is your task as a writer to fit your writing around the quotation: "In incorporat­ing fragmentary quotations into a text, phrase the surrounding sentence in such a way that the quoted words fit into it logically and grammati­cally – as if there were no quotation marks" (13.11).
Also note that you are misquoting your source! It does not say that the Seljuks did not construct a civilization on their own. It says that they were insulted of not being capable of it. It says nothing about whether or not that insult was true.
